# How to toggle bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to toggle tool tip when the button is clicked. How to do?

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary fa fa-plus" data-target="tooltip" title="show more"> </button>

  <script>
      $("button").click(function(){
      $("button").toggleClass("fa-minus");

      // what is the code to toggle tool tip        

      });
  </script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rajagopalx/bmfk0a42/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the title attribute on the button.

```
if ($("button").hasClass("fa-minus")) {
    $("button").attr("title","show more");
}
else {
    $("button").attr("title","show less");
}
```

Comment: How to toggle it again when button is clicked ?